# (Xamarin Forms) How to show toolbar when navigate from "Main Page" to any page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm having a problem in **Xamarin forms**:

I want to open a any page in my app when standing in the main page of app.

**Example**: Flow of my app:

Main page -> List detail contact -> Detail Contact -> Edit Contact -> ...

I want to navigate from "Main page" to "Detail Contact" without having to go through "List detail contact"

- At **AppDelegate.cs**, I send a message to "MainPageViewModel.cs"

  `MessagingCenter.Send(new AddNewContactEventMessage(), nameof(AddNewContactEventMessage));`
- At method **Initialize()** of "MainPageViewModel.cs", I subcrible message and navigate to "Contact Detail Page":

  ```
          MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AddNewContactEventMessage>(this, nameof(AddNewContactEventMessage), message =>
      {

          Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
          {
              try
              {
                  await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(ContactDetailPage), new ContactManagerNavigationParameters()
                  {
                      ContactId = 0,
                      ManagerId = ActivatedUser.UserId
                  });
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  Logger?.Exception(ex);
              }
          });
      });
  ```
- But when "Detail Contact" is open, Toobar of page is hidden.
- Why Toolbar is hidden? And how to fix it?

Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using MessagingCenter to navigate???

Comment: I'm coding 3D touch on iOS with Xamarin Forms. I can't navigate to certain page in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Give a title to the page in xaml or from code behind, that shows toolbar .